# Having troubles using Valgrind with WSL on CLion

Tags: valgrind, clion, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Working on Windows 10, enabled WSL and installed Ubuntu.
WSL toolchain configured, I can build and run stuff on CLion, everything works perfectly except for Valgrind.

I used the path:

```
\\wsl$\Ubuntu\usr\bin\valgrind
```

but everytime I try to run a Memcheck I get:

```
Valgrind executable is not found
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use Posix path `/usr/bin/valgrind`.
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/memory-profiling-with-valgrind.html#valgrind-wsl

Works for me.